# Where is it appropriate to post about a new Linux software utility that I want some feedback about?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a new Linux utility that I'd like to get a small handful of folks to try out...

It would be appropriate for the readers on ServerFault.   But, I don't think it meets the guidelines for posting on that site.  Where would it be appropriate to post this?

Comment: Understand that **StackExchange is a network of Q&A sites**, not a recruiting or feedback site. I'm not sure your request would be suitable anywhere on the network.

Comment: Not sure about, but for the interface [ux.se] or for the code itself [codereview.se] ; but it's more about part / functionality than for the whole software

Answer (score 2):

If you want feedback, there is technically no site for this.

Why, because getting feedback on something is not part of Stack Exchange. Well the only feedback allowed here is for the meta questions with [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) or [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) but that is a different thing. You can however, find a chatroom whose topic is Linux and maybe try there but your question may be off-topic there.